# Is there a way to add parameters to image url

Tags: php, html

I want image request from browser to be read by PHP script. The url should look like this:

```
<img src="www.example.com/image/size/image-name/userid">
```

I was able to get the request, this how the code is.

```
$img = file_get_content("imageName");
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $img;
```

The browser received the response but the image not displaying.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Regards

Comment: You need to link this image with id? why don't use simple <a> attribute with id?

Comment: Have you made sure that path you are trying to read the image data from is correct? file_get_contents will only return false, if it can’t find the file. Enable proper PHP error reporting if not the case already, comment out the `header` line, call the URL directly in your browser, and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you stripped off letter `s` from the end of `file_get_contents()` function name. 
The code below will work just fine:

```php
<?php
$img = file_get_contents("imageName");

header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $img;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It's important to inform browser about size of the file.

```
$img = file_get_contents($path,true);
$size = filesize($path);
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
header ("Content-length: $size");
echo $img;
exit;
```